# Minting Native Assests - Error Building the Raw Transaction: $output variable

Tags: native-assets, mint

I'm following [this](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting#build-the-raw-transaction-to-send-to-oneself) doc on how to mint native assets with Cardano and have received an error that I can't get around. The problem is with the $output variable in the $tx-out parameter of the cardano-cli transaction buildraw command. I don't see where this variable is assigned in the documentation. Any thoughts or ideas on how I'm missing the variable?

```
option --tx-out:
unexpected "+"
expecting white space or multi-asset value expression
```

[image: tx-out parameter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right it is missing the documentation, but basically, it is the your UTXO output amount.

You can calculate it by finding out the amount of lovelaces on the UTXO you are spending in your `tx-in` minus the fees.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll assign the output variable accordingly. Thank you very much!

Comment: I see the formula further in the documentation, in a "Note" section: 

3. the output in Lovelace (ada) (output = input amount — fee).